# Is there any way to verify output whether i am getting right output

Tags: shell

I am running this command:

```
if [[ "uname -r" == "3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64" ]]   ; then
    echo "Command succeeded"
else
    echo "Command failed"
fi
```

Getting the following error in the output:

```
Command failed
```

Need your help on these, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are comparing two literal strings `"uname -r"` and `"3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64"`, they are of course not equal.

You want the result of the command execution (uname -r), you should use `$(uname -r)`

```
if [[ "$(uname -r)" == "3.10...." ]] ....
```